# Problems creating an if block

Tags: php

The code that I'm using

```
    if ($_REQUEST('addOrEdit') == 'add') {
      $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("insert into ITEM (tracker, date, significance, obsolete, description,data, programs, topics, lastModifiedBy) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");

//      $stmt2->execute(array($tracker,$_REQUEST['date'],$_REQUEST['significance],$_REQUEST['obsolete'],$_REQUEST['description'], null, $_REQUEST[program],$_REQUEST[topic],null);

    }
```

If I comment out the if line and the closing parenthesis, it works (on AWS LAMP instance). But otherwise this is breaking my page, and when I try to load it, I see nothing but a blank page.

Elsewhere on my page I am echoing out the `$_REQUEST['addOrEdit']` and it shows `add`

The problem appears to be with my `if` usage(?) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: @04FS Thank you for this link. I'm hopeful that this is going to speed up my development greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote braces to fetch request parameters in `if` statement. Replace Braces to square brackets.

```
if ($_REQUEST['addOrEdit'] == 'add') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the *syntax error* (which may be a typo as your question contains the correct syntax later on), as Rahul has pointed out, you could be more defensive and check the key exists within the array.

```
if (array_key_exists('addOrEdit', $_REQUEST) && $_REQUEST['addOrEdit'] === 'add') {
```

Answer (score 0):

$_REQUEST is a global variable of type array.Its not a function.
You can access the variable using [] not this ().
so try this

if($_REQUEST['addOrEdit'] == 'add'){
    your code
}